# Prove the following inequality without using induction: $\frac{1}{2^k-1}\leq \sin^{2k}\theta+\cos^{2k}\theta\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> How to prove the following inequality (without using induction)? 
>   $$\frac{1}{2^k-1}\leq \sin^{2k}\theta+\cos^{2k}\theta\leq 1,\quad k\in\Bbb N.$$

Comment: For the RHS, $\sin^{2k}\theta + \cos^{2k}\theta \leq \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ since $|\sin(x)|, |\cos(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Do you know  about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: You could see this as minimizing $x^k+y^k$ subject to the constraint $x+y=1$

Comment: Excellent.Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for Left hand ,we  use Holder inequality
$$(\sin^{2k}{\theta}+\cos^{2k}{\theta})(1+1)^{k-1}\ge (\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{\theta})^k=1$$
so
$$\sin^{2k}{\theta}+\cos^{2k}{\theta}\ge\dfrac{1}{2^{k-1}}$$
not $\dfrac{1}{2^k-1}$

Comment: How to use Holder inequality?

Comment: one simple form with Holder inequality :$$(a^3+b^3)(x^3+y^3)(u^3+v^3)\ge (axu+byv)^3$$

Comment: and more ugly holder $$(x^n_{1}+y^n_{1})(x^n_{2}+y^n_{2})\cdots (x^n_{n}+y^n_{n})\ge (x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n}+y_{1}y_{2}\cdots y_{n})^n$$

Comment: Now you understand?

Comment: @Stella If you may you can also see it as a consequence of [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) applied to the convex function $f(x) = x^n$, then$\displaystyle \frac{a^{n}+b^{n}}{2} \ge \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: @r9m,It's Nice!

Comment: Thanks dear Math110 & r9m. <3

Answer (score 6):

We have to assume $k>0$ or the term $1/(2^k-1)$ would be meaningless. The case $k=1$ is trivial, so I'll assume $k>1$.

Consider, for $k\ge0$, the function
$$
f_k(\theta)=\sin^{2k}\theta+\cos^{2k}\theta
$$
which has period $\pi/2$. Its derivative is
\begin{align}
f_k'(\theta)
&=2k\sin^{2k-1}\theta\cos\theta-2k\cos^{2k-1}\theta\sin\theta\\[3px]
&=2k\sin\theta\cos\theta(\sin^{2k-2}\theta-\cos^{2k-2}\theta)\\[3px]
&=k\sin(2\theta)(\sin^{2k-2}\theta-\cos^{2k-2}\theta)
\end{align}
We need to find where the derivative vanishes. It happens at $\theta=0$, and $\theta=\pi/2$ or at points where
$$
\sin^{2k-2}\theta-\cos^{2k-2}\theta=0
$$
that is, $\tan\theta=\pm1$, that is $\theta=\pi/4$ (in the interval of periodicity).

So we have the critical points $0$, $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$. We have
\begin{align}
f_k(0)&=1\\
f_k(\pi/4)&=\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
\end{align}
Since
$$
\frac{1}{2^k-1}<\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}
$$
for $k>1$, the result is proved.